# SQL select and Group by

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL like this.

```
OrderID  ItemID  ItemPrice   ItemType
1        A       100         1
1        B       50          1
1        C       10          0
2        A       100         1
2        F       60          0
3        G       10          0
```

So I want to get out put like this?

```
OrderID ItemPrice -Type= 1  ItemPrice -Type= 0
1             150                     10
2             10                      60
3             10
```

Do you have any idea about the SQL command to use?
I think it is group by order ID and Item type.

Comment: Is that really what you want to call your field names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a pivot transformation. There are a few ways to do it, but my favorite way is using CASE inside SUM:

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 0 THEN ItemPrice ELSE 0 END) AS Type0_Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 1 THEN ItemPrice ELSE 0 END) AS Type1_Price
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY OrderId
```

This scales nicely if you have more than two types. All you have to do is add another `SUM(...)` line in your select list without having to change the rest of the query.

I *think* this will perform well, since the calculations in the SELECT list can be done without incurring additional row scans or lookups. That's the downside of self-joins and sub-selects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
DISTINCT(orderId),
(Select   SUM(ITEMPRICE) from table where Itemtype=1 group by ORDERID) as ItemType1, 
(Select   SUM(ITEMPRICE) from table where Itemtype=0 group by ORDERID) as ItemType0

from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should work for you.

```
SELECT t1.OrderID, 
ItemPrice-Type1 = SUM(t1.ItemPrice), 
ItemPrice-Type2 = SUM(t2.ItemPrice)
FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN TableName t2 on t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID and t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID
WHERE t1.ItemType = 1 AND t2.ItemType = 0
GROUP BY t1.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this work?:

```
SELECT
    OrderID, 
    SUM(ItemPrice*ItemType) Type1,
    SUM(ItemPrice*(1-ItemType)) Type0 
FROM 
    TableName 
GROUP BY OrderID
```